# Conversão c# wpf ICollection e ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, cast, collection

Tenho uma lista ICollection generica e preciso converter para ObservableCollection, então não sei qual classe é para converter em

`ObservableCollection<MyClass>.`

Já estou a alguns dias em busca dessa resposta, isso é possível? como faria?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o construtor que recebe uma IEnumerable como parâmetro e passar a sua coleção para converter.

Ficaria assim:

```
ICollection<MyClass> listaCollection = new List<MyClass>();

ObservableCollection<MyClass> observableCollection = new ObservableCollection<MyClass>(listaCollection);
```

Segue a documentação sobre os construtores desta classe: [aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=netframework-4.7.2#construtores)

Comment: mas no caso, eu nao sei qual classe é, então não tem como eu criar como você criou